# Excel vba: object variable or with block variable not set error when returning Object from function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a function that should return an `Excel.Application` Object:

```
 Dim ExcelApp As Object
 Set ExcelApp = getExcelApp()



Function getExcelApp() As Object
        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelApp.Visible = False
        ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False

        getExcelApp = ExcelApp
End Function
```

But I get a `object variable or with block variable not set` error. What is wrong and how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you're missing the [`Set` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement) (which is needed because you're assigning an *object*).

But you're creating one object, setting it up, then assigning it to a different object for returning. You could instead assign everything directly to the return variable. 
**A more concise function would be:**

```
Function getExcelApp() As Object
    Set getExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With getExcelApp
        .Visible = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
   End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

`Set` for objects, so `set getExcelApp = ExcelApp`

Also, If you are calling this from Excel, then you'll already have the correct class library available, so I'd use

```
Function Get_Excel() As Excel.Application

Set Get_Excel = New Excel.Application
Get_Excel.Visible = True
'     etc, etc
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Set ExcelApp = getExcelApp()
    Debug.Print ExcelApp.Name

End Sub

Function getExcelApp() As Object

    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False

    Set getExcelApp = ExcelApp

End Function
```

It would print the name of the new ExcelApp. In this case `Microsoft Excel`. I have also changed `ExcelApp.Visible` to `True` and the function, returning an object should be with a `Set`.